# Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта. Excel

Tags: c#, winforms, excel

Добрый вечер всем. Я добавил в форму **DataGridView** и **Button**. Кнопка должна была экспортировать в **Excel**. Но выдает ошибку: ***Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта***

```
         //Создание DataTable
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        //Добавление колонки
        foreach( DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView.Columns)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(column.HeaderText, column.ValueType);
        }
        //Добавление строки
        foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView.Rows)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add();
            foreach(DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][cell.ColumnIndex] = cell.Value.ToString();//Ошибка здесь
            }
        }
        //Экспорт в Excel
        string folderPath = @"C:\\Excel\\";
        if(!Directory.Exists(folderPath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);
        }
        using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
        {
            wb.Worksheets.Add(dt, "Customers");
            wb.SaveAs(folderPath + "DataGridViewExport.xlsx");
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Замените `cell.Value.ToString()` на `System.Convert.ToString(cell.Value)`.

Comment: Спасибо что помогли.)))

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего, где-то `cell.Value=null?` по этому `cell.Value.ToString()` выдает ошибку. Можно заменить на `string.Format("{0}", cell.Value)` или предварительно проверить на `null`.